# How can I make my elements fade in and out as their display attributes are changed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On the click of a button (using onclick), I am toggling the display style of three divs between `none` and `block`. I am at a loss as to how I can make these divs fade in and out. I am open to using JQuery as well but I do not see how I could integrate andéor use the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions here. Any suggestions as to how I can go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the function that is being called `onclick` for reference, this is where the display attribute of my divs is toggled.

```
function divSelector(count){
            if (count == 1){
                var temp = document.getElementById('second-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'none';

                temp = document.getElementById('third-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'none';

                temp = document.getElementById('first-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else if (count == 2){
                var temp = document.getElementById('first-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'none';
                temp = document.getElementById('third-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'none';

                temp = document.getElementById('second-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'block';   
            }
            else if (count == 3){
                var temp = document.getElementById('first-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'none';
                temp = document.getElementById('second-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'none';

                temp = document.getElementById('third-about-text');
                temp.style.display = 'block';   
            }   
            else{
                console.log("Count is nothing.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully contained example for you:

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j4Mrn/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            .btn {height:50px;width:50px;margin:50px 50px;}
            .one{background-color:red;}
            .two{background-color:green;}
            .three{background-color:blue;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                count = 1;

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    divSelector(count);
                    count++;
                    if (count==4) count = 1;
                });

                function divSelector(count){
                    if (count == 1){
                        $('#first-about-text').fadeIn(1000);
                        $('#second-about-text').hide();
                        $('#third-about-text').fadeOut(1000);;
                    }else if (count == 2){
                        $('#first-about-text').fadeOut(1000);
                        $('#second-about-text').fadeIn(1000);
                        $('#third-about-text').hide();;
                    }else if (count == 3){
                        $('#first-about-text').hide();
                        $('#second-about-text').fadeOut(1000);
                        $('#third-about-text').fadeIn(1000);;
                    }else{
                        console.log("Count is nothing.");
                    }
                }

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="first-about-text" class="btn one"></div>
    <div id="second-about-text" class="btn two"></div>
    <div id="third-about-text" class="btn three"></div>

    <input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click Me">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are open to JQuery try this way:

I am just assuming your markup here. Give a common class to your divs say `content` so that they are accessible with one selector.

```
 $('.content:gt(0)').hide(); //start up hide all but the first one.

function divSelector(count){

       var currElem = $('.content:eq(' + count-1 + ')'); //get the div based on the count number eq will give the div based on its index and position in DOM. Assuming these divs appear in DOM one after the other.
        $('.content').not(currElem).fadeOut('1000', function(){ //Fade out other content divs
             currElem.fadeIn('1000'); //Fade in the current one.
        });

    }
```

- [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)
- [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)
- [:fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
- [:fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

providing your markup will clear out the assumptions and help provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you need?

```
function divSelector(count){
                if (count == 1){
                    $('#second-about-text').fadeOut();
                    $('#third-about-text').fadeOut();
                    $('#first-about-text').fadeIn();
                }
                else if (count == 2){
                    $('#second-about-text').fadeIn();
                    $('#third-about-text').fadeOut();
                    $('#first-about-text').fadeOut();  
                }
                else if (count == 3){
                    $('#second-about-text').fadeOut();
                    $('#third-about-text').fadeIn();
                    $('#first-about-text').fadeOut();   
                }   
                else{
                    console.log("Count is nothing.");
                }
            }
```