# detecting a div's position based on it's attaribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have three divs and I want to execute a command on a div that happens to be on top of the other divs in a container without referencing it's name or id.I am randomizing the position of the divs and I basically  want the div whose height is equal to `10px` to change it's color attribute to red when a specific number is generated, whilst the other divs maintain their default color. I have tried the following but I can't think of any way to do this without using the div's id.

```
      var current = 0;
      current++;

    var topArrtcard = document.getElementById("card-answer");
    var topArrtcard1 = document.getElementById("card-answer1");
    var topArrtcard2 = document.getElementById("card-answer2");


if(current === 0 ){


       topArrtcard.style.color = "red";  // is it possible not use the id in order to make the change 
       topArrtcard1.style.color = " #996600";
       topArrtcard2.style.color = " #996600";   

    }else  if(current === 1 )
   {

       topArrtcard.style.color = "#996600";
       topArrtcard1.style.color = "red";
       topArrtcard2.style.color = " #996600";   

    }else if(current === 2){


       topArrtcard.style.color = "#996600";
       topArrtcard1.style.color = " #996600";
       topArrtcard2.style.color = "red";   

    }else {
         topArrtcard.style.color = "#996600";
       topArrtcard1.style.color = " #996600";
       topArrtcard2.style.color = "#996600";   
    }
```

the variable `current` increments by 1 each time the page is loaded. I hope this is clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What `10px attribute`? That's not in your sample code. Question not clear. What generates the new number? That is where you will likely do your check.

Comment: I have made the necessary changes. thank you @gibberish

Comment: Why not just run a loop around the `topArrtcardx`'s, and test `if (topArrtcardx.style.height == '10px'){ do whatever}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not opposed to using jQuery (and why would you be? In many ways it's simpler than javascript with much less to type)...

I cannot see from your code (at this moment) what will trigger an event that you can use to do the testing that you want.

However, if something does happen to the DIV, then perhaps you can use that event to make the changes you want. You would reference the changed DIV as `this`.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256867/how-can-i-make-my-elements-fade-in-and-out-as-their-display-attributes-are-chang/17256987#17256987) that looks somewhat similar